# DefaultKafkaProducerFactory with multiple JsonSerializer mappings

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

i'm going through spring documentation and found that we can have multiple mappings for single producer factory [spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#serdes)

```
senderProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
senderProps.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "foo:com.myfoo.Foo, bar:com.mybar.bar");
```

But it is unclear for me how to create `Producerfactory` like below

```
@Bean
public ProducererFactory<Foo, Bar> kafkaProducerFactory(KafkaProperties properties,
JsonSserializer customSerializer) {

return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties.buildProducerProperties(),
    customSerializer, customSerializer);
}
```

According to my knowledge `Foo` must be key and `Bar` must be value right?, and what is this `customSerializer`? i'm looking for clear example with much more info.

My question is i wish to have single `ProducerFactory` and `kafkatemplate` that produces multiple type message to kafka, for example `Foo`, `Bar`,`Car` is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; this

```
senderProps.put(JsonSerializer.TYPE_MAPPINGS, "foo:com.myfoo.Foo, bar:com.mybar.bar");
```

is only for when you define the deserializer when using properties only.

When using the `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` and `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` constructors that take fully built serializer/deserializer objects directly, you must configure the deserializer yourself.

```
typeMapper = new DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper();
typeMapper.setIdClassMapping(myTypeMappingsMap);
deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
deserlialzer.setTypeMapper(typeMapper);
```

(and similarly for the serializer).

Comment: can you point out me to an example? sorry i'm really bad at understanding things without example, and `take fully built serializer/deserializer` this means a custom serializer/Deserializer ?

Comment: It's in your question: `return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(properties.buildProducerProperties(),
    customSerializer, customSerializer);` You are providing the serializer not Kafka. I assume the Consumer there is a typo. The property is only used if Kafka builds the serializer.

Comment: There's an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/samples/sample-02/src/main/java/com/example/Application.java#L61). It's using a message converter rather than a serializer, but the same technique applies.